# Fullcalendar.js V5 Scheduler don't print vertical Lines if there is more than 1 page to print

Tags: css, printing, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so if you think I do something wrong, be open to give me your Feedback. Thanks in advance.

I use the fullcalendar.js library, everything works fine except for printing.

I tried everything and I searched hours and hours in the Internet. So I'm pretty sure, that my question is not a duplicate, because no answers helped me with my problem so far.

If I print the calendar, it works perfect if I just have to print 1 page.
If there is more than one page to print, the vertical Lines of the month are not visible.

**Printing 1 Page**
[Print preview with vertical lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8aJd.jpg)

**Printing more than 1 Page**
[Print preview without vertical lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIscC.jpg)

I tried:

- every browser and it is still the same problem.
- every css options, also !important
- Html2canvas, Html2pdf
- everything in the print settings
- every other solution I found in the web

I'm using also the Bootstrap 4.0.0 libary and jquery 3.5.1

Did somebody had the same problem or an idea how to solve it?

Thank you all for your support.

Simba

Comment: Remove any other CSS (including print-specific CSS) from your page except the fullCalendar CSS, and see if you still have the issue. If you do, raise a bug - see https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me

```
@media print {
    .fc-timeline-slot-lane > div {
    position: absolute !important;
    border-left: 0.5px solid #ddd;
    margin-left: -0.5px;
    min-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Review: Out of context I don't know what you have changed or done to find your solution. It may be correct but this is a chance to teach while answering.

Comment: Thank you very much Ebud. Your workaround is working perfectly for me and I'm very thankful.

@JasonIsMyName: I was understanding what Ebud did, but you're right. Ebud added the code above to the media query. Inside of the <td> is an empty <div> and Ebud changed the position to absolute (because with position:relative is min-height not working) and then he was set the border to solid.

I hope this workaround will also help other peoples.
Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Their official demo is not printing correctly as well https://fullcalendar.io/demos

Answer (score 0):

My fix is in the fullcalendar css file you can find this selectors just change the `display: none` to `display: block;`;

```
.fc-media-print .fc-timegrid-slots,
.fc-media-print .fc-timegrid-axis-chunk,
.fc-media-print .fc-timeline-slots,
.fc-media-print .fc-non-business,
.fc-media-print .fc-bg-event {
  display: none; //change this to block
}
```